# Using flycheck/flymake on kernel source tree

Tags: linux, emacs, flycheck

Is there a easy/automated way to configure flycheck or flymake 
to show error annotations while writing on a file
in the linux kernel source tree? Assuming I am working on
fs/proc/cmdline.c I would like flycheck to go down
two directories and do a "make fs/proc/cmdline.o" and
then annotate the result. Assuming ARCH and CROSS_COMPILE
is set externally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd been thinking of doing this myself - here's what I've got:

You need to find the base of the kernel source tree, so the default `flymake` deal of looking for `Makefile` is counter productive.  We'll add our own file which doubles for locating the source base, and for wrapping the normal kernel makefile:

Add a file `flymake.mk` to the base of the kernel source tree (configure for your own cross-compilation needs):

```
ARCH=mips
CROSS_COMPILE=mips-linux-gnu-

export ARCH
export CROSS_COMPILE

.PHONY: check-syntax
check-syntax:
    make -f Makefile $(patsubst %_flymake.o,%.o,$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(CHK_SOURCES)))
```

The gist is to strip out "_flymake.c" and only compile the real file, and build the file for real, rather than just for syntax.  This avoids us accidentally creating `file_flymake.o`

We'll need to convince flymake to look for `flymake.mk` and run `check-syntax` against it - add these to your .emacs:

```
;; Build a custom command-line using flymake.mk
(defun flymake-get-kernel-make-cmdline (source base-dir)
  (list "make"
    (list "-s"
              "-f"
              "flymake.mk"
          "-C"
          base-dir
          (concat "CHK_SOURCES=" source)
          "SYNTAX_CHECK_MODE=1"
          "check-syntax")))

;; Search for flymake.mk to locate kernel tree base
(defun flymake-kernel-make-init ()
  (flymake-simple-make-init-impl 'flymake-create-temp-inplace t t "flymake.mk" 'flymake-get-kernel-make-cmdline))

;; Register against .c files under /linux/ or /kernel/
;; Since the list is parsed in order use `push`
(push '(".+/\\(linux\\|kernel\\)/.+\\.c$" flymake-kernel-make-init) flymake-allowed-file-name-masks)
```

Limitations:

- Can't parse header files
- Can't parse flymake temp files `source_flymake.c` (make sure you ignore flymake markup until it has run over the saved files).  I have a keystroke that forcefully re-runs flymake.
- No support for flymake in external modules
- Needs pre-registration of the path-matcher (see `push` line above) - I don't know enough about flymake to allow it to override a single buffer as a one-off.

The header, temp and external modules limitations could be overcome by patching the kernel Makefile itself, which for now I wanted to avoid.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the flymake snippet. I fiddled around a bit and came up with the below flycheck snippet (see post below). Greetings Konrad

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Gregs flymake snippet here is one for flycheck i have come up with:

```
(defun utils/flycheck-search-linux-makefile ()
  "Search for linux top `Makefile' "
  (labels
      ((find-makefile-file-r (path)
        (let* ((parent (file-name-directory path))
               (file (concat parent "Makefile")))
          (cond
           ((file-exists-p file)
            (progn
              (with-temp-buffer
                (insert-file-contents file)
                (if (string-match "VERSION = [0-9]+[[:space:]]*PATCHLEVEL" (buffer-string))
                    (throw 'found-it parent)
                  (find-makefile-file-r (directory-file-name parent))
                  ))))
           ((equal path parent) (throw 'found-it nil))
           (t (find-makefile-file-r (directory-file-name parent)))))))
    (if (buffer-file-name)
        (catch 'found-it
          (find-makefile-file-r (buffer-file-name)))
      (error "buffer is not visiting a file"))))

(flycheck-define-checker utils/flycheck-linux-makefile-checker
  "Linux source checker"
  :command
  (
   "make" "C=1" "-C" (eval (utils/flycheck-search-linux-makefile))
   (eval (concat (file-name-sans-extension (file-relative-name buffer-file-name (utils/flycheck-search-linux-makefile))) ".o"))
   )
  :error-patterns
  ((error line-start
          (message "In file included from") " " (file-name) ":" line ":"
          column ":"
      line-end)
   (info line-start (file-name) ":" line ":" column
         ": note: " (message) line-end)
   (warning line-start (file-name) ":" line ":" column
            ": warning: " (message) line-end)
   (error line-start (file-name) ":" line ":" column
          ": " (or "fatal error" "error") ": " (message) line-end))
  :error-filter
  (lambda (errors)
    (let ((errors (flycheck-sanitize-errors errors)))
      (dolist (err errors)
        (let* ((fn (flycheck-error-filename err))
               (rn0 (file-relative-name fn default-directory)) ; flycheck-fix-error-filename converted to absolute, revert                                                                                  
               (rn1 (expand-file-name rn0 (utils/flycheck-search-linux-makefile))) ; make absolute relative to "make -C dir"                                                                                
               (ef (file-relative-name rn1 default-directory)) ; relative to source                                                                                                                         
               )
          (setf (flycheck-error-filename err) ef)
          )))
    errors)
  :modes (c-mode c++-mode)
  )

(defun utils/flycheck-mode-hook ()
  "Flycheck mode hook."
  (make-variable-buffer-local 'flycheck-linux-makefile)
  (setq flycheck-linux-makefile (utils/flycheck-search-linux-makefile))
  (if flycheck-linux-makefile
      (flycheck-select-checker 'utils/flycheck-linux-makefile-checker))
  )

(add-hook 'flycheck-mode-hook 'utils/flycheck-mode-hook)
```

- utils/flycheck-search-linux-makefile : This searches for a top-level linux Makefile that contains VERSION = .. PATCHLEVEL = ...
- utils/flycheck-linux-makefile-checker : The flycheck checker, it uses "make" "C=1" "-c" "..." that requires sparse to be installed

not perfect but usable.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a `flymake.mk` makefile like

```
## case 2: called within docker and cross env
ifeq (${_FLYMAKE_WRAPPED},)

_c_sources := $(filter %.c,$(CHK_SOURCES))
_h_sources := $(filter %.h,$(CHK_SOURCES))

_make_wrapped = $(MAKE) \
        kbuild-file=$(abspath $(firstword ${MAKEFILE_LIST})) \
        _FLYMAKE_WRAPPED=$1 _FLYMAKE_TYPE=$2 M=$(dir $*) $3

check-syntax:   $(addprefix .check-syntax_,${_c_sources} ${_h_sources})

$(addprefix .check-syntax_,${_c_sources} ${_h_sources}):.check-syntax_%:
        +$(call _make_wrapped,2,c)

## case 3: checking the files
else ifeq (${_FLYMAKE_WRAPPED},2)

-include $(dir ${CHK_SOURCES})/Makefile
-include $(dir ${CHK_SOURCES})/Kbuild

# Reset object/module list
obj-y :=
obj-m :=
lib-y :=
lib-m :=
always :=
targets :=
subdir-y :=
subdir-m :=

__build: check-syntax
.PHONY: check-syntax

clean_checkflags = $(filter-out -M% -g% -Wp,-M%,$1)

check-syntax: ${CHK_SOURCES}
        $(CC) $(call clean_checkflags,$(c_flags)) -c -o /dev/null -S $<

endif
```

It works both with headers files and uses the temporary flymake files.